# Admin on Rest graphql client returns empty resources

Tags: graphql, admin-on-rest

Im am trying to get to grips with admin on rest with graphql client. I am using 'aor-graphql-client-graphcool' and an endpoint on launch pad.
Debugging the app shows a zero length array assigned to the resource key.  The types/queries look ok so I think introspection is working OK.

```
introspectionResults {types: Array(39), queries: Array(9), resources: Array(0)}
```

I have implemented getPageOf[Resource]s and get[Resource] queries in my endpoint but its not clear in the documentation if I need to do anything more than this.

I am initialising the client in a next.js react component as shown in the documentation:

```
componentDidMount() {
  buildApolloClient({
    clientOptions: {
      uri: 'https://xxxxxxxxx.lp.gql.zone/graphql'
    }
  }).then((restClient) => {
    this.setState({ restClient });
  });
}
```

I have also tried to disable introspection and passed in custom queries but in this case I get a null for the introspectionResults.

I am wondering the following:

- Is launchpad compatible with the graphcool client?
- Do I need more in config in my client initialisation to get the resources populated.
- Is admin on rest the silver bullet it claims to be, i.e. can it decipher my schema via introspection queries and present the data.

I really hope so because this thing looks so cool!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need introspection or a schema.js file to initialize the admin-on-rest (aor) with the available resources and types of your graphql server. AOR does a lot, but since graphql is evolving and also does not standardize everything (e.g. expected variables or their naming conventions), you will have to either adapt the simple data provider for graphql (see examples/demo for graphql) or write your own.

How I started: If you are just getting started with a new graphql server/schema, then base your own example on the examples/demo (as described in the AOR doc). Be sure to use the "next" branch of the repository. Begin by stepping through the ra-data-graphql/src/index.js and ra-data-graphql-simple/src/index.js that will be called from your example. This will show you where your introspection results and the default/simple dataProvider are not matching.

Comment: Thanks, but not the problem. Introspection works fine. The graphql (standard) INTERFACE types in my schema are causing AOR to reject the schema. INTERFACE is not optional if you claim to support GrahpQL...

Answer (score 1):

If your introspection returns a empty `resources`, you will mostly have to provide an adapter to your introspection function.

By default, `react-admin` is expecting a certain schema shape (more details [here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-graphql-simple#expected-graphql-schema))

Eg, for a `Post` resource, you should have `allPosts` query to fetch a list of `Post`

```js
type Query {
  Post(id: ID!): Post
  allPosts(page: Int, perPage: Int, sortField: String, sortOrder: String, filter: PostFilter): [Post]
  _allPostsMeta(page: Int, perPage: Int, sortField: String, sortOrder: String, filter: PostFilter): ListMetadata
}
```

If in your backend, instead of `allPosts`, you have `postList` for eg, you can map `allPosts` to `postList` with the introspection options

```js
export const introspectionOperationNames = {
    //schema,
    [GET_LIST]: resource => {
        return `${inflection.camelize(resource.name, true)}List`;
    },
    ...
};
```

Same for `CREATE`, `GET_ONE`, `GET_MANY`, `GET_MANY_REFERENCE`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

You can find a nice example of custom introspection [here](https://github.com/RobertLowe/react-admin-5168-reproduction/blob/master/src/introspection.js)